SFTP Connection Issues
I manage an SFTP server and personally have no issues connecting. Many clients also use it successfully but a handful have issues. Some example client side messages:

Failed to authenticate. Verify the credentials and try again. Domo is
ready, but the credentials you entered are invalid. Verify your
account credentials and try again. Domo is ready, but we were unable
to connect to the SFTP server. Please check your settings and try
again.


Permission Denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic). Connection Closed.

On the server side I see:
Oct 15 08:00:36.604 pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user <user>
Oct 15 08:00:34.946 pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <user> (uid=1020) by (uid=0)
Oct 15 08:00:34.650 Accepted publickey for <user> from <IP> port 21191 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<hash>

So it looks like the client connects fine but doesn't like something and quickly disconnects.
Misc Details:

All users use private key auth, not password
Running in AWS on EC2 - Amazon Linux 2023
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
Added sshd config options to support clients with old keys:

HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa


No firewall/IP filtering
Same user worked with a different SFTP client (WinSCP vs Domo)

As I said, it works fine for most users so I am at a loss to what might cause this. Any ideas are much appreciated.

If it works for most people, the problem is more likely to be on the client's side.

Yeah, "Permission Denied (pubickkey...) implies a PEBKAC issue.   Most likely they have not unlocked the private key, or the public key you are using for them does not correspond with their private key.

Totally agree it seems like a client issue. One user responded today that WinSCP worked fine while Domo still doesn't. My only concern is that a lot of this started after an OS upgrade that included OpenSSH upgrade. I had to reenable ssh-rsa since that was defaulted to disabled. Maybe there is something else affecting some client? Thanks!
